# Nginx + php7.1-fpm - connection using Firefox returns php file instead of result of its execution

Tags: php, firefox, nginx, chrome

I have nginx (1.10.3-1+deb9u2) on Debian 9.6. I have installed php7.1-fpm from external repository (sury.org). I have simple php file executing `phpinfo()` function (and nothing more), simply to see if everything works. Now for the funny part. I have it on embedded device with "normal" ethernet interface - if I connect from my PC using this interface I got expected results. But when I connect via USB, so that there is RNDIS-like (or RNDIS, I'm not sure) network interface created, things do not work as expected, that is if I connect using Firefox, I see a dialog asking me where I want to save file - which is exactly the file that should be executed by nginx + fpm combo. But when I connect using Chrome, I get expected result, so standard phpinfo()-generated page.

I believe that configuration is absolutely standard Nginx stuff. Does anyone has any idea how could that happen? If behavior were different depending on the interface that I connect on, it would be pretty obvious information that for some reason Nginx refuses to execute my request using php module. But it depends on the browser that I use and this is bewildering to be honest.

I checked how connections are made in both Fireox and Chrome using developer tools and it seems that they are basically identical, in addition there are no redirections, so that's not it. I haven't tried wget/curl yet and I can't do it now, but no matter what the result will be this is still inacceptable.

Any ideas? No matter how wild they are?

EDIT (configuration):

I've been able to confirm nginx configuration. It is as follows:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;
    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;
    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;
    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;
    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;
    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
    server_name beaglebone;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ ^/.*\.html$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

I thought that maybe there *are* two server blocks, but as you can see there is only one. What is strange is that when I connect using Firefox and nginx (?) serves file instead of executing it, there is nothing in /var/log/nginx/access.log.

Comment: How many `server` blocks does your configuration have? Where is the PHP file located - is it the same as the default Nginx root?

Comment: From memory - nginx root is /var/www/html and this is where PHP file is located. There were no extensive changes from default nginx configuration, so I believe that there is only one `server` block block. And nginx listens on 0.0.0.0:80 (or its equivalent). I thought for a moment that difference might be between IPv4 and IPv6, but I explicitly use IPv4 in the browser (`http://192.168.7.2/info.php` to be precise.)

Comment: You can confirm the full configuration with `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`). My guess is that there is a default server block which will download files form the default document root.

Comment: Thanks for information. I've attached result of `nginx -T` but there is only one `server` block. And please note, that with identical configuration and identical URL I get different results on Chrome and Firefox. Firefox tries to download file, Chrome displays expected result.